# Chrome extension message sending from background to content issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to send the current active URL from any updated tab to it's respective content script with the code below. I'm having trouble confirming receipt of any message in the content script/page console. However, the `console.log`'s in `background.js` are showing up..

I've also noticed that sometimes the changeInfo.url will send as `undefined`? If I remove the `if (changeInfo.url) {` conditional from `background.js`, the background script will log out 2-3 times per page-load, with the latter instances logging changeInfo.url as `undefined`.

I'm new to Chrome extension development, what am I missing? Thanks!

*background.js :*

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( 
    function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.url) {
        console.log(tabId, changeInfo.url, tab);
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage( tabId, {
            message: 'hello!',
            url: changeInfo.url
        })
    }
});
```

*content.js :*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("this is the url:" + request.url)
    }
)
```

Comment: `changeInfo.url` will only be defined when the tab url has changed [according to the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onUpdated) which is why it's sometimes `undefined`. Keep in mind also that when a tab is updated it can be in one of multiple states, so the event is usually fired multiple times, first with `changeInfo.status` set to `loading` and later to `complete`.

Comment: 1. `url` cannot be undefined in console.log because it won't pass your `if` condition, so I guess you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page hence the old incorrect version of the code is still running.
2. Multiple changes of the URL occur when the site is using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) to change the URL of the tab without reloading it. If you don't want to observe these changes you don't need a background script at all: just use `location.href` in the content script.